# in rails, how can I get all parameters of a model after joining with other models, get an ActiveRecord::Relation which count's method returns a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uniq

Lets suppose I have the following models:

```
class Item
  # (name, price, location, quantity)
  has_many :purchases
end

class Purchase
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  # (name, age)
  has_many :purchases
end
```

I need to Find all the unique items with name "cd" bought by person named "bob"

Then in my view I need:

- `@items` to contain unique records
- `@items.count` to return a number
- access all the attributes of each item when looping:

  ```
  <% @items.each do |i| %>
    <%= "#{i.name}, #{i.locatiton}, #{i.quantity}" %>
  <% end %>
  ```
- @items to be an ActiveRecord::Relation (so I can paginate)

My query until now looks something like this:

```
@items = Item.joins(:purchase => :person).where('person.name' => 'bob')
```

leaving @items like it is has the problem that contains duplicate items

What I've tried:

1) `@items.uniq`
removes the duplicates but returns an array and I need an ActiveRecord::Relation

2) `@items.select('distinct(items.name)')`
removes the duplicates but returns a relation containing only the item.name and I need all the attributes

3) `@items.group('items.name')`
removes the duplicates and returns a relation but the count method returns an OrderedHash not a number
yes I can count the keys but I have the same views for other relations that return a number when calling the count method on the relation.

I really don't know what else to try, any suggestion?

Comment: I wonder if this is an uncommon thing? or I'm doing things the wrong way? I just want uniq results that I can paginate afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do:

```
@items.select("DISTINCT(`items`.`name`), `items`.*")
```

And use what you need from Items. Did you tried it?

Comment: this doesn't work, when I add 'items.name' to the select I get back duplicates again